# How to copy a url of a file in Dropbox folder on mac?

Tags: python-2.7, shell, python-3.x, command-line, dropbox-api

I tried with many other options like using User ID and all, but they seem to be changed from dropbox now, I ddnt get the User ID.

Also, the pythonscript which can be run from command line didn't work.

Can anybody help me out on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can manually get the URL to a file by right-clicking on the file and selecting "Copy Dropbox link". If you'd like to get the URL programmatically, try using the Dropbox API.

You can use the `/create_shared_link_with_settings` endpoint for generating a sharable URL:
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#sharing-create_shared_link_with_settings

The Python SDK may also be helpful for you.